# Why didn't Troi feel the mind of the Borg Queen?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, borg

In ST:TNG 2:16, in the Federation's first encounter with the Borg, Deanna Troi states:

> We're not dealing with an individual mind. They don't have a single leader. It's the collective minds of all of them.

She then follows this up by saying:

> A single leader can make mistakes, which is far less likely in the combined whole.

Based on this, it seems that the Borg were neither connected to, nor guided by, a single consciousness of the Queen, but were rather an amalgamated consciousness of disparate sentient minds. If the Collective mind was controlled by the Queen, shouldn't Troi have felt a single consciousness of the Queen, albeit divided amongst otherwise mindless drones?

Comment: I think the idea of a Borg Queen was retcon'd into Star trek with First Contact

Comment: Can you imagine the bandwidth required to route every drone through the Queen?  Micromanaging all those units would be a nightmare...  Give 'em a patrol route, and leave them to it, just like a giant RTS

Comment: While the queen is almost certainly a retcon, we can probably explain Troi not sensing her by comparing the queen to an orchestra conductor. You don't hear the conductor, but they do direct the orchestra.

Comment: @Chronocidal All the while trying to seduce Data.....

Comment: proximity probably for starters. PICARD: Yes, ...I remember you. You were there all the time. But that ship and all the Borg on it were destroyed.
BORG QUEEN: You think in such three-dimensional terms. How small you've become. Her mind was deep in the system during the crew's other encounters - in First Contact, she is physically present

Comment: In-universe she might have been in a heavily shielded area of the cube

Comment: @SpacePhoenix Is there a canonical limit put on Betazoid abilities by physical objects? Troi can feel through ships and shields, and IIRC also empathize non-corporeal life-forms.

Comment: The betazoid in "Tin Man" could communicate telepathically with Tin Man from a long way off

Comment: I may be mistaken, but the Borg Queen is not an individual - merely a physical manifestation of the Borg's collective consciousness to be used when dealing with human-like species. Also (and this is largely speculation) the queen could possibly be used as a fail-safe to preserve the memory of a single cube/sphere in case that sphere was destroyed, thus leading to the queen ejection pod in Picard.